# JavaScript: Is the nesting of constructor instances inside a constructed 'wrapper' problematic?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, nested, prototype

Hopefully this question won't be flagged as *too* subjective but I'm newish to OOP and struggling a bit when it come to sharing data between parts of my code that *I think* should be separated to some extent.

I'm building a (non-geo) map thing (using leaflet.js which is superduper) which has a map (duh) and a sidebar that basically contains a UI (toggling markers both individually and *en masse*, searching said marker toggles as well as other standard UI behaviour). Slightly confused about organisation too (how modular is too modular but I can stumble through that myself I guess). I am using a simple JSON file for my settings for the time being.

I started with static methods stored in objects which is essentially unusable or rather un-reusable so I went for nested constructors (kinda) so I could pass the parent scope around for easier access to my settings and states properties:

```
function MainThing(settings) {
  this.settings = options;
  this.states = {};
}

function SubthingMaker(parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
}

SubthingMaker.prototype.method = function() {
  var data = this.parent.settings.optionOne;
  console.log(data);
  this.parent.states.isVisible = true;
};

MainThing.prototype.init = function() {
  this.subthing = new SubthingMaker(this);
  // and some other fun stuff
};
```

And then I could just create and instance of `MainThing` and run `MainThing.init()` and it should all work lovely. Like so:

```
var options = {
  "optionOne": "Hello",
  "optionTwo": "Goodbye"
}

var test = new MainThing(options);
test.init();

test.subthing.method();
```

Should I really be nesting in this manner or will it cause me problems in some way? If this is indeed okay, should I keep going deeper if needed (maybe the search part of my ui wants its own section, maybe the map controls should be separate from DOM manipulation, I dunno) or should I stay at this depth? Should I just have separate constructors and store them in an object when I create an instance of them? Will that make it difficult to share/reference data stored elsewhere?

As regards my data storage, is this an okay way to handle it or should I be creating a controller for my data and sending requests and submissions to it when necessary, even if that data is then tucked away in simple JSON format? `this.parent` does really start to get annoying after a while, I suppose I should really be binding if I want to change my scope but it just doesn't seem to be an elegant way to access the overall state data of the application especially since the UI needs to check the state for almost everything it does.

Hope you can help and I hope I don't come across as a complete idiot, thanks!

P.S. I think the code I posted works but if it doesn't, its the general idea I was hoping to capture not this specific example. I created a much simpler version of my actual code because I don't want incur the wrath of the SO gods with my first post. (Yes, I did just use a postscript.)

Comment: You're not nesting constructors, you're nesting instances. This is perfectly fine, it's known as [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: You can and should nest arbitrarily deep when it makes sense, but keep the [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I've just realised my title is stupid, I'll change it. I meant am I okay to create instances of my constructors within constructors. Although since I'm actually doing it through and initialisation function, I may be wrong twice and am just getting confused. I think the issue is that my initial construction is essentially acting as a wrapper for my inner constructors that contain all the logic, but the wrapper constructor also holds the data. I'm not sure if that clarifies anything, I'll just change the title.

Comment: Yes, creating other instances in a constructor is totally reasonable. Look at that `this.states = {};` (which creates an `Object`), do you think it's any different there?

Comment: Yeah, your `init` method *is* an oddball. It should just go inside the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I guess the fact that its less obvious (being obfuscated by the fact that it needs to be instantiated explicitly rather than being there by default) just threw me off and made me think it was somehow different when in reality they're all just objects regardless of how the are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object may contain as many other objects as are appropriate for doing it's job.  For example, an object may contain an Array as part of its instance data.  Or, it may contain some other custom object.  This is normal and common.

You can create/initialize these other objects that are part of your instance data in either your constructor or in some other method such as a `.init()` method whichever is more appropriate for your usage and design.

For example, you might have a `Queue` object:

```
function Queue() {
   this.q = [];
}

Queue.prototype.add = function(item) {
    this.q.push(item);
    return this;
}

Queue.prototype.next = function() {
    return this.q.shift();
}

var q = new Queue();
q.add(1);
q.add(2);
console.log(q.next());    // 1
```

This creates an Array object as part of its constructor and then uses that Array object in the performance of its function.  There is no difference here whether this creates a built-in Array object or it calls `new` on some custom constructor.  It's just another Javascript object that is being used by the host object to perform its function.  This is normal and common.

Comment: And when referencing the parent scope in order to call functions or access data should I do it in the way I show in the code example in my question (passing a reference to the correct 'this') or is there a better way? Or should I be doing something else when it comes to data?

Comment: @peterallen - If an object needs a reference to another object (there are no such things as actual "parent" objects in Javascript), you can pass that reference to it whenever you need to.  It can be done in the constructor like you are doing or later on in a specific method call.

Answer (score 0):

One note is that what you are doing with your `MainThing` and `SubthingMaker` violates [OOP principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), because they are too tightly coupled and have too wide access to each other internals:

```
SubthingMaker.prototype.method = function() {
  // it reads something from parent's settings
  var data = this.parent.settings.optionOne;
  console.log(data);
  // it changes parent state directly
  this.parent.states.isVisible = true;
};
```

While better idea could be to make them less dependent.

It is probably OK for the `MainThing` to have several "subthings" as your main thing looks like a top-level object which will coordinate smaller things.

But it would be better to isolate these smaller things, ideally they should work even there is no `MainThing` or if you have some different main thing:

```
function SubthingMaker(options) {
  // no 'parent' here, it just receives own options
  this.options = options;
}

SubthingMaker.prototype.method = function() {
  // use own options, instead of reading then through the MainThing
  var data = this.options.optionOne;
  console.log(data);
  // return the data from the method instead of 
  // directly modifying something in MainThing
  return true;
  this.parent.states.isVisible = true;
};

MainThing.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  // MainThing calls the subthing and modifies own data
  this.parent.states.isVisible = this.subthing.method();
  // and some other fun stuff
};
```

Also to avoid confusion, it is better not to use parent / child terms in this case. What you have here is aggregation or composition of objects, while parent / child are usually used to describe the inheritance.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this in the first place but was worried about duplicating data. I could easily split up the relevant options and route the data to the required constructor without issue. My main issue is saving map 'states' (markers, popups, layers, etc.) which change frequently. I don't want to be duplicating them every time I change something (or should I?). Perhaps I should create a 'data controller' and request/send the data from/to that object via it's own get/set methods? Additionally, can you call constructor methods from different constructors?

Comment: You can call constructors for other objects inside the constructor. And it is complex to answer other questions where you are talking about the specific implementation. I think your markers, popups and layers should also be objects. Again, from the OOP perspective, having getters/setters for everything is not good, because you open the object internals to the world. Instead of doing `marker->setX(x); marker->setY(y)` you better do `marker->move(x,y)` or even delete the old marker and create the new one, see [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).